# Play Protect and Codename One

Tags: codenameone

Every time I install an apk release via the "Codename One Build" app on Android 10, Play Protect annoys me.

Is there a way to make sure the apps made with Codename One don't mess with Play Protect? Every time I'm asked if I want to send the app I'm developing to Google: it is very annoying and inappropriate. Probably during the development of an app I have to remove it and reinstall it hundreds or thousands of times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with the advanced protection program. I don't think there's much we can do in terms of the app to make it smoother. It's just Google being difficult as usual. You can disable play protect but not for a gsuite in advanced protection and can't currently disable it for a specific app as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok, I disabled Play Protect. As a result, the installation of the apps made with Codename One is much faster and there are no annoying screens. On the other hand, as you have noticed, in this way I disabled Play Protect for all the apps, and not only the ones developed by me.